# error installing a program becuase the admin has set a block on it?

Tags: installation, steam

When i try to install the program Steam, when it starts to download an error message pops up saying "the system administrator has set up policies to prevent this installation". the problem is im the only user on this computer and thre are no parental securities set up or anything like that. i dont know what to do

Comment: Are you free of all malware infections?

Comment: is this a computer at work/school?

Answer (score 0):

Google says this might have something to do with a broken Microsoft Visual C++ install... Try uninstalling it, restarting it and reinstalling it in program manager, if you have issues uninstalling it then grab the msi cleanup utility from  http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/MSI-cleanup-utility-3889c8db and use it to uninstall, then restart and reinstall.